# is there really no predifined rotation matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am just wondering, if there is really no predefined function in MathWorks Matlab which gives you some kind of this:

`R = rot(a)`

with `rot(a)` being `[cos(a) -sin(a); sin(a) cos(a)]`

Comment: See [`rotx()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/rotx.html) (likewise `roty()` and `rotz()`).

Comment: @beaker, this is part of a toolbox and not part of regular Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function built in. But you basically have written it yourself, so save it (below) and call it: rot2d().  If you want the 3d rotation matrix, post another question. If you want to rotate row vectors, transpose the matrix shown, and put the vector before the matrix when you multiply them.

```
function [R] = rot2d(a)
%ROT2D Return 2D rotation matrix
%   Returns matrix that rotates a column vector by angle a (in radians).
%   Example 1: v=[1;1]; w=rot2d(pi/4)*v; {w now = [0;1.414]}
%   Example 2: Rotate 3 (or more) [x;y] pairs at a time: 
%       v1=[1,0]; v2=[1;1]; v3=[0;1]; vc=[v1,v2,v3]; wc=rot2d(pi/6)*vc;
%   The examples show the correct multiplication order.
%   Note that this is not the matrix to use if you want to express a
%   vector in terms of a coordinate system rotated by angle a. 
%   Use w=inv(rot2d(a))*v to express vector v in a coordinate system
%   rotated by a.
R = [cos(a),-sin(a);sin(a),cos(a)];
end
```